# Django AUTH_USER_MODEL not registering custom User class

Tags: python, django

I've got this setup in my models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models

```
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **kwargs):
        . . .
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
        . . .

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    . . .
```

In settings, I have done this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authentication.Account'
```

but I continue to get this error:

```
AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'authentication.Account'
```

Please I would like to know why and how to fix this

Comment: Please show the full traceback, and your full `Account` model.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly specify the manager inside your custom user model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = AccountManager()
    ....
```